# Is it possible to set height as percentage of width when width is set to 100% using CSS

Tags: css

I coded an image optimization helper called [sharp-watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp-watch) that generates metadata for images including their aspect ratio and [blurhash](https://blurha.sh/).

I would like images to be responsible which works by default for `img` tags (when width is set to `100%`, height is set using image aspect ratio).

Problem is the aspect ratio is only know once image is downloaded. Given I know the aspect ratio ahead of time (using `sharp-watch` metadata), is it possible to set width to `100%` and height using aspect ratio from metadata using CSS (not JavaScript)?

I need to set the height to display blurhash while image loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by Aspect Ratio
like below

```css
.container {
   background-color: red;
   position: relative;
   width: 100px;
   padding-top: 56.25%; /* 16:9 Aspect Ratio */
}
```

```html
<div class="container"> 
</div>
```

Try to change padding-top and you will get different result

For more detail check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_aspect_ratio.asp)